# How can i make javascript wait for my variable to get data, then display data. I'm using socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm using socket.io here. Because im fetching data from an external API, my username doesn't have time to get fetched, so when first submitting a message, the username doesn't appear, but on the second time it does because the API got fetched. PS: I can not fetch the API on the front end. I had to make a server to use it.
Here is the code:

```
 var socket = io("ws://localhost:4000/");

document.getElementById("message").addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("sendbtn").click();
  }
});

var send = () => {
  socket.emit("message", document.getElementById("message").value);
  socket.emit("username", document.getElementById("username").value);
  document.getElementById("message").value = " ";
  return false;
};

socket.on("user", (user) => {
  username = user;
});

var username = " ";
var message = " ";

socket.on("message", (msg) => {
  message = msg;
  document.getElementById("messages").innerText = username + message;
  console.log(username);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just disable sending until the username is there.

Notice how I changed the default value of username to empty string.

```
var send = () => {
  if (username) {
    socket.emit("message", document.getElementById("message").value);
    socket.emit("username", document.getElementById("username").value);
    document.getElementById("message").value = " ";
  }
  return false;
};

socket.on("user", (user) => {
  username = user;
});

var username = "";
var message = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use promises on the server side to async/await the response from the API call to emit the "message" and "username" (again, from the server).

You can send whatever messages you want to the server.
Then, the server will make the appropriate API call - that API call should return a promise.

So, the function that will emit "message" or "username" on the server should be an async function with a call to the API function, like so:

//api.js

```
function getMyData(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
       fetch().success({resolve(data)}).fail({reject(error)})
    })
}
```

//serverSocket.js

```
async function emitStuff(){
  let result
  try{
  result = await getMyData;
   socket.emit("message", result)
  }catch(err){
    //throw err
  }
}
```